# Web Scraping for Coding Schools

Tags: web-browser, web, scraping

Is there a fast and efficient way to create some web crawler or scraper to search for coding schools, their contact info, and location and put put them into an excel document or Google Sheet?

Comment: For any particular programming language?  For Python, you have [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)  [Comaprison](https://hexfox.com/p/scrapy-vs-beautifulsoup/)

Comment: Ill read into those. Just do understand you correctly, with these tools you can enter in like "coding school name" and it will return all desired values?

Comment: Those are not stand alone tools, they are libraries which will help with Python coding. I don't know of any such standalone tools. You could specify to search for pages containing a string, such as "coding school", and then search within all such pages for "name", "address", etc.  As with all such operations, it's Garbage In, Garbage Out, so you need to find the correct search string. I am not sure that "coding school" will find all sites that you want it to.